# Copying across native libraries (non-jar) into dmg when building Netbeans / Ant java project

Tags: deployment, netbeans-8

In my NetBeans java 8 project there are a few native libraries that have to be copied over to the `lib` directory. From many search attempts I have found that NetBeans does not have a way to do this through the GUI. So I added the following:

For a normal local build and run:

```
<condition property="isMac">
    <os family="mac" />
</condition>
<condition property="isWindows">
    <os family="windows" />
</condition>

<target name="-copy-win" if="${isWindows}">
    <echo message="copying windows libraries"/>
    <copy todir="${basedir}/dist/lib"> 
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.dll"/>
    </copy> 
</target>  

<target name="-copy-mac" if="${isMac}">
    <echo message="copying mac libraries"/>
    <copy todir="${basedir}/dist/lib"> 
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.dylib"/>
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.so"/>
    </copy> 
</target>    
<target depends="-copy-win,-copy-mac" name="-pre-jfx-deploy"/>
```

For "package as image only" option:

```
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy-mac" if="${isMac}"> 
    <copy todir="${basedir}/dist/bundles/MyApp.app/Contents/Java/lib"> 
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.dylib"/> 
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.so"/> 
    </copy> 
</target>    
<target name="-post-jfx-deploy-win" if="${isWindows}"> 
    <copy todir="${basedir}/dist/bundles/MyApp/app/lib"> 
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/native" includes="**/*.dll"/> 
    </copy> 
</target>    
<target depends="-post-jfx-deploy-mac, -post-jfx-deploy-win" name="-post-jfx-deploy"/>
```

But for packaging as EXE / DMG the native libraries are not copied over. I can kinda fix this by define my own `fx:deploy` task in `build.xml`, but this is clunky because NetBeans already creates one using some javascript in `jfx-impl.xml`.

Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I think I have something working.

1. Create a folder called `native` in the top-level project directory and put your dlls and dylibs in there.

Then in `build.xml`:

2. Add the `-copy-win` and / or `-copy-mac` targets (as above in my question)
3. Add two targets:

   `<target depends="-jfx-copylibs,-rebase-libs,jfx-deployment,-copy-win,-copy-mac" name="-post-jar"/>`

   `<target depends="-copy-win,-copy-mac" name="-pre-jfx-deploy"/>`

The first makes sure the libraries are copied over to `dist/lib` when running the project in netbeans, the second makes sure they are copied over to `dist/lib` when deploying the project.

4. Add a target `-pre-init`, inside past the entire macro `<macrodef name="deploy-deploy">` from `jfx-impl.xml` in the `nbproject` directory, and change the value in `<property name="pp_deploy_fs2" value="lib${file.separator}*.jar"/>` to `value="lib${file.separator}*.*`

The entire file is in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/geometrikal/d347b008523847c8fb42173f0e4216de).

You can then load the native libraries in code like:

```
String dir = Paths.get(MainController.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()).getParent().toString();
if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS) {
    System.load(current + "/lib/native_library.dll");
}   
else if (SystemUtils.IS_OS_MAC_OSX) {
    System.load(current + "/lib/native_library..dylib");
}
```